# advance mathematics c++ libraries

Tags: c++, math

what popular advance mathematics libraries for c++ are present out there, so that they can be used as a 1 stop solution and avoiding reinventing the wheel ?

Comment: what kind of mathematics?

Comment: I did not specify because I end up having utilities in different fields, tensors, matrix algebra, functional analysis, calculus, group theories, interpolation, etc.

Comment: The rest seem reasonable, but it seems unlikely that there is a library out there for group theory... unless you mean cryptography...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/)  -- it's in C, but I use it all the time to avoid re-writing the Numerical Recipes code.

Answer (score 1):

Intel's MKL (Math Kernel Library) is to be looked at especially if doing large scale matrix operations; it's C based, but should not really be an issue IMO.

Other than that, maybe the boost math library could be interesting as it is free. (but I have no experience with it, so YMMV).

Max.

Comment: Most of the MKL is based on the BLAS and LAPACK interfaces, so it is really Fortran-based, not C-based (it's obvious when you use it since matrices are assumed to be column-major and everything gets passed by pointer).  It has C language bindings, though, which make it easier to use with C++.  Boost uBLAS is only a BLAS implementation, but there are LAPACK bindings in the Boost incubation (I've never used them, so I can't make a recommendation on their use; I've generally just done the binding myself when I've needed to use LAPACK with uBLAS's matrix classes).

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, you will probably not find a single library to handle all of the areas you listed.  For matrix algebra, I've heard good things about the [Eigen C++ library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) from coworkers who are using it.

Answer (score 0):

For commercial libraries, both NAG (Numerical Algorithms Group, http://www.nag.co.uk/) and IMSL ( http://www.vni.com/products/imsl/ ) are standards and provide industrial-strength numerical analysis algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

look through the list and mix-and-match.  You want very many things, unlikely any single package is going to do them all.

http://www.oonumerics.org/

octave is the only one that is going to be more or less comprehensive (functionality comparable/clone to Matlab)

http://www.mathias-michel.de/download/howto-octave-c++.ps

Answer (score 0):

For group theory there is [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org).